# How to retrieve variable in $Global namespace via variable

Tags: powershell-3.0

I created a variable like this:

```
Set-Variable -name $CredVarName -value (Get-Credential $UserName) -option readonly -scope global
```

I would like to retrieve it via a another variable:

```
$VarName = $CredVarName  

$Global:$VarName
```

but that doesn't work:

> `$Global:$VarName`
>
> `Variable reference is not valid. '$' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.`

Any ideas on how to get the variable via another variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using dynamic variable names, so consider using `Get-Variable` instead of `$Global:`:

```
Get-Variable -Name $VarName -Scope Global -ValueOnly
```

Comment: $CredVarName is not null, it is set before the Set-Variable cmdlet is called.  Both $CredVarName and $UserName are parameters passed in to the function that contains the Set-Variable statement.

Comment: @Number8: I see - I've made an adjustment to my answer.